# How to access original context with Fiber

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to use an async third party lib call and get the result.
So I wrap the callback method inside the Meteor.bindEnvironment because meteor code must always run within a fiber:

```
server(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (device) {
  device.on('foo', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
    var someVar = this.getSomeVar();
    MyCollection.insert(someVar, data);
  }));
}));
```

But when I use this method I can't access original context of the callback
function, so this.getSomeVar is always undefined.

To prevent this, I use Fiber directly and it seems work. But I am not sure
if it's reliable:

```
server(function (device) {
  device.on('foo', (data) {
    var someVar = this.getSomeVar();
    Fiber(function() {
      MyCollection.insert(someVar, data);
    }).run();
  });
});
```

Does this way has some side effects?

Comment: Arrow functions don't keep lexical context of `this` so if you want to use `this` context of device.on you need to use normal function, not the arrow one

Comment: I have removed arrow function. What do you think about usage of Fiber?

Comment: About reliability - `someVar` will mean the same it meant outside of Fiber callback since this is the same scope so I believe it is reliable.